# Как отобразить все параметры к которым применяются GPO?

Tags: сервер, администрирование

Пришел в контору с кучей GPO где было много админов и каждый просто вписывал что хотел, по этому есть политики которые называются "Это здесь по тому что без нее другие не работают (почему то)"

Существует ли ПО которое может пробижатся по всем GPO что созданы и создать табличку где будут перечислены все параметры которые управляются GPO их значения, к кому применяются и в какой политике они указаны (одни и те же параметры могут быть указаны в разных политиках)

Хочу найти дубляжи, противоречищие друг другу параметры и оптимизировать общее количество правил